# Comparing two files

Tags: file, comparison

Can anyone create a script for a file comparison?

The pseudo code looks like this

- extract line 5 from file 1
- save it in another variable,
- extract line 5 from file 2,
- save it in another variable,
- if
   variable 1 is not equal to variable 2 (while allowing for differing characters at positions 11 and 12 from the end of line)

  - then fail
  - else
    pass

Comment: What files do you need to compare?
And what kind of result is expected when comparsion is finished?

Comment: Is anyone getting paid to "create a script" for you?

Comment: As everyone knows, there is a lot of money to be made from selling scripts one gets as answers on SO.

Comment: @Charles My point should be obvious, if he wants help then ask for what he needs help with, last I checked SO wasn't created so people can get people to do their work for them. I mean if it is let me know, I'd love to be able to relax while others do my work.

Comment: No I'm definitely not getting paid for this! I'm not a software developer either, so these skills are a bit out of my scope. I need them to integrate with a test tool (yes I'm a tester!).

Many thanks Charles for answering this, the support means a lot. I should have mentioned tho that I need it on windows. (sorry!). 

Many thanks in advance to anyone who answers.

Comment: I ought to note that the files are in txt format but not recognisable. I don't know the file structure though the data is delimited by space

Answer (score 1):

Unix shell?  Pass the fileneames as arguments to the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
a="$(head -n 5 < $1|tail -n 1)"
b="$(head -n 5 < $2|tail -n 1)"
test "$a" = "$b" && (echo The same; exit 0)
echo Different; exit 1
```